# Is this set in $\mathbb R^3$ a regular surface?

Tags: differential-geometry, 3d

Currently, I am reading Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces by Manfredo P. Do Carmo. While solving exercises problems, I came across this question and I have tried for a while and came to conclusion that the only problem for this set to be regular surface is it boundary, but could not prove rigorously. Have a look at the question below.

Let two points $p(t)$ and $q(t)$ move with the same speed, $p$ starting from $(0,0,0)$ and moving along the $z$-axis whereas $q$ starting at $(a,0,0)$, $a$ nonzero real number and moving parallel to $y$-axis. The line through $p(t)$ and $q(t)$ describes a set in $\mathbb R^3$. And I am not clear whether the set is a regular surface or not. I think that the boundary of the set is the only problem but cannot prove rigorously. It is clear that for $t>0$ and $0<s<1$, the parametrization $X(t,s)=(sa,st,t(1-s))$ satisfies all the conditions for it to be a chart of a regular surface. So, I have concluded that $s=0,t>=0$ and $s=1,t>=0$ are the only problem. Does anybody have any suggestion. Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: $t$ can be any real number? I'm not sure there is a boundary.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruled_surface

Comment: @CyclotomicField I think the surface is parametrized by $\Bbb{R}_{\geq0}$ and so the boundary is at $t=0$. But I will leave it to OP to confirm this.

Comment: @Servaes yeah if $t \geq 0$ there is a boundary line between $(0,0,0)$ and $(a,0,0)$ which will not have a well-defined tangent.

Comment: Note that every point on the surface is of the form
$$q(t)+s(p(t)-q(t))=(a,t,0)+s\big((0,0,t)-(a,t,0)\big)=\big((1-s)a,(1-s)t,st),$$
for some $t,s\in\Bbb{R}$. It is not entirely clear from your description whether you require $t\geq0$. Either way all points on the surface satisfy
$$xy+xz-ay=0,$$
and this is precisely your surface if you allow all $t\in\Bbb{R}$.

Comment: The question is saying that p starts from (0,0,0) and q starts from (a,0,0), which implicitly saying that at some finite time t the process begins. And without loss of generality, one can assume t starts at 0.

Comment: Also, the way you have parametrized the surface with s and t, s lies in the range [0,1]. The line (a,t,0) [which is obtained when s=0] for all t>=0 [even for all real t] is a boundary of the surface. But, the surface xy+xz-ay=0 is a regular surface as it is a graph.

Answer (score -1):

EDIT 1:

Not sure if this would be useful for working on it further.

```
ParametricPlot3D[{4  t, -v  t , v  t}, {t, -2, 2}, {v, -2, 2}, 
 AxesLabel -> {XX, YY, ZZ}]
```

Some velocity ( here 4) or any other link function $f(v,t)$ may need to be given *extra* as an $x$ coordinate to the given speeds say 2, in order to span/connect two skew lines along $(y,z) $ directions to define a flat surface which in the first case makes up triangular patches through origin.

[image]